# Retornar valor gerado a partir do foreach

Tags: php, mysql

Basicamente, tenho este `foreach` para criar dinamicamente o texto da seleção:

```
foreach ($table['exists'] as $item) {
            switch ($i) {
                case 0:
                    echo($item.' = "'.$_POST[$item].'" AND');
                    break;

                case $len - 1:
                    echo(' '.$item.' = "'.$_POST[$item].'"');
                    break;

                default:
                    echo(' '.$item.' = "'.$_POST[$item].'" AND ');
                    break;
            }
            $i++;
        }
```

Ele me retorna basicamente isso:

```
cep = "{CEP inserido}" AND rua = "Delfinópolis" AND dispo = "1"
```

Se este array for inserido na função (pega o array 'exists' e compara com o inserido no formulário):

```
$tabela = ['table'  => 'ceps',
                 'exists' => ['cep', 'rua', 'dispo'] ];
```

Precisava pegar este valor criado dinamicamente e inserir em uma variável para por na minha função:

```
$existe = DBRead($table['table'], "WHERE {$minhaVarEntraAqui}");
```

Comment: Concatene, crie uma variável fora do `foreach`, e em cada condição do `switch` coloque `$var = ...`.

Comment: @Edilson não entendi esta solução. Pode elaborar um pouco mais a resposta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$i=0;
        $len = count($table['exists']);
        foreach ($table['exists'] as $item) {
            switch ($i) {
                case 0:
                    $marray[0][$i] = $item.' = "'.$_POST[$item].'" AND ';
                    break;

                case $len - 1:
                    $marray[1][$i] = $item.' = "'.$_POST[$item].'"';
                    break;

                default:
                    $marray[2][$i] = $item.' = "'.$_POST[$item].'" AND ';
                    break;
            }
            for ($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++)
                echo $marray[$j][$i];
            $i++;
        }
```

creio que isso vá resolver o problema